# Can you use a font as a parameter?

Tags: java, function, methods, parameters, fonts

Okay here is a really quick Q&A question:
If I have declared a font in a Java applet, can I send it to a different method as a parameter?

Example:

```
methodName(String str, Font font)
```

Can I do this?^^^

Comment: Did you try it? Why did you think it better to ask humans rather than to try it, effectively asking the compiler?

Comment: Have you tried to do so?

Comment: Trying your code yourself has several benefit over asking it from someone.. If you ask, you learn only that specific thing.. If you try, you get to learn several ways that can generate `Errors` and `Exception`.. So, you should always try to compile your code.. Rather than asking someone - Is there any compiler error in my code??

Answer (score 2):

Anything that extends `Object` or is a primitive type can be sent as a parameter. This includes `Font`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any object may be passed as a parameter to the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, have you not tried this before posting the question?

Answer (score 0):

Dan said it correctly, and politely. You can pass just about anything into a function. This includes: primitives(int, double, char, etc), objects(Font, String, Scanner, etc), and user defined classes.